# How to disable react native timeout

Tags: react-native, request

I have some request code in react-native that looks like this.

```js
export default function App() {
    const [text,setText] = useState('')
    const [open,setOpen] = useState('')
    const [openrmse,setOpenrmse] = useState('')
    const [close,setClose] = useState('')
    const [closermse,setClosermse] = useState('')
    const [low,setLow] = useState('')
    const [lowrmse,setLowrmse] = useState('')
    const [high,setHigh] = useState('')
    const [highrmse,setHighrmse] = useState('')
    const [date,setDate] = useState('')
    
    const getData = async () => {
        console.log('http://127.0.0.1:5000/'+text);
        try {
         const response = await fetch('https://******.ngrok.io/'+text);
         const json = await response.json();
         setOpen(json.Open[0]);
            setOpenrmse(json.Open[1]);
            setClose(json.Close[0])
            setClosermse(json.Close[1]);
            setLow(json.Low[0]);
            setLowrmse(json.Low[1]);
            setHigh(json.High[0]);
            setHighrmse(json.High[1]);
            setDate(json.time);
       } catch (error) {
         console.error(error);
       }
    }
```

Now I have a flask server which I ported using "ngrok http".
However the processing takes around 8 minutes. My app used to wait for the result but now it just shows a network error saying the request timeout. How do I disable this timeout and if not possible is there any way to make a request that doesn't timeout? Thanks in advance.